# Prove that if $6 \mid (2a + 4)$ and $9 \mid (12 + 3b)$ then $3 \mid (a + b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Could you help me with the problem below?

> Prove that if $6 \mid (2a + 4)$ and $9 \mid (12 + 3b)$ then $3 \mid (a + b)$.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you're new here, I'd like to share some things about Math.SE. **Firstly**, it would help if you show what you have already tried. This helps us know where you got stuck, and allows us to better answer your question. **Secondly**, we use $\LaTeX$ to format math on this site. TMM has edited the question to incorporate this--take a look, and try to use this for future questions; using $\LaTeX$ increases the chances that you get high-quality answers. For help with $\LaTeX$, see [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

Show that $3$ divides $a+2$ and $b+4$, and deduce that $a+b+6$ (and a fortiori $a+b$) is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 3):

$\rm\begin{eqnarray}\rm {\bf Hint}\ \ \ \dfrac{4\!+\!2a}{6} = &&\rm\dfrac{2\!+\!a}{3},\ \ \ \dfrac{4\!+\!b}{3} = \dfrac{12\!+\!3b}{9}\ \  \ both \in\Bbb Z \\  
\\
\rm therefore\   &&\rm\dfrac{2\!+\!a}{3}\, +\, \dfrac{4\!+\!b}{3} \,-\, 2\,=\,\dfrac{a\!+\!b}{3}\,\in\,\Bbb Z
\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 2):

$$6 \mid (2a+4) \implies 3 \mid a+2 \,\, \text{(Why?)}$$
$$9 \mid (3b+12) \implies 3 \mid b+4 \,\, \text{(Why?)}$$
Hence, $$3 \mid (a+2+b+4) \,\, \text{(Why?)} \implies 3 \mid (a+b+6) \,\, \text{(Why?)} \implies 3 \mid (a+b) \,\, \text{(Why?)}$$

Comment: The first steps are like to devide e.g. 2/6=1/3 and 4/6=2/3.. Add additional members and 
I cant understand the last step... how to remove the number 6 ?

Comment: If you read my answer, you should see how to remove the 6 from the left hand side and that should give you your understanding...

Comment: I cant still understanding how to remove the 6 from left hand side... the only way is to sum -6 on two sides?

Comment: That is how you remove the six!  You subtract 6 on both sides.  Then you can factor a 3 out of -6!  So $a+b+6=3(k_1+k_2)$ becomes $a+b=3(k_1+k_2-2)$.

Answer (score 2):

$6|(2a+4)$ implies that $2a+4=6k_1$ for some integer $k_1$ and $9|(12+3b)$ implies that $3b+12=9k_2$ for some integer $k_2$.
So $a+2=3k_1$ and $4+b=3k_2$.
Thus $a+2+4+b=3(k_1+k_2)$.

The rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Since $6 \mid (2a+4)$, let $$(2a+4) = 6p.$$
$$a = (6p-4)/2.$$
$$a = (3p-2) \tag{1}$$

Again since $9 \mid (12+3b)$, let $$(12+3b) = 9q.$$
$$b = (9q-12)/3.$$
$$b = (3q-4)\tag{2}$$

(1) + (2) gives you: $$(a+b) = 3(p+q)-6 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (a+b) = 3(p+q-2).$$

Hence $3$ divides $(a+b)$ or $3 \mid(a+b)$.

Hope the answer is clear!